# Writing pseudo-sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql, pseudocode

Today I passed an interview and thez ask me this :

> Write pseudo SQl statements to create database tables to store the products of a basic websho. Each product has a name, a price, a creation date ans may belong to several categories. Categories have a name and a flag to indicate whether the category is private or public.

Also:

> Write a SQL query to find the list of products that belong to more than 5 public categories.

My knowledge of sql is pretty limited, i just pass 2 hours searching on the web for pseudo-sql statements without result.

Can someone explain me what it is and eventually respond to the answers so i'll know ? (interview already fail so you dont do my homework ahahah)

Thanks!

Comment: There are many resources in the world to learn SQL -- books, videos, tutorials, classes.  You should invest in actually learning the subject rather than focusing on passing tests.

Comment: if i focus on passing test, its because i need a job. Also my question is not about proper SQL, i know there is a lot of ressourse on that, its about pseudo-sql. Can you explain what it is ? :)

Answer (score 1):

```
product(pro_id, pro_name, price, date)
```

`pro_id` is the Primary key

```
category(cat_id, cat_name, cat_flag, cat_type)
```

`cat_id` s the primary key

```
procat(pro_id, cat_id)
```

`pro_id`, `cat_id` are primary key together

**Query:**

```
select pro_id from procat where cat_id in (select cat_id from category where cat_type = 'public') group by pro_id having count(*)>2
```